# asp.net dropdown list always select 0 index with postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

working on a simple project after click a button i'm clear all textbox text and I want dropdown list select it's 0 index value..........I'm trying to write some jquery code to complete this work

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
                $("#productNameDDL")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            });
        });
```

but don't work this code what should have I do now.Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with asp.net, the problem is most likely the `id` of the DropDownList. Use:

```
$("#<%= productNameDDL.ClientID %>").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Asp.net renames the `ID` propery of a Control on the client side to ensure unqiue id's. See the [Microsoft Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

**UPDATE**

To change the SelectedIndex of a DropDownList programatically you can use this.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    productNameDDL.SelectedIndex = 0;
    //or
    productNameDDL.SelectedValue = "value";
}
```

Comment: Actually I want reset dropdownlist on every postback through a button click

Answer (score 1):

Clear the form instead, if you can't then best solution will be

```
$("#target").val($("#target option:first").val());
```

Or you can use

`$('select option[value="your_value"]').attr("selected",true);` .

If you want to select option by content

```
$('select option:contains("it\'s me")').prop('selected',true);
```

You need to use the :contains(text) selector to find via the containing text.

Also jQuery prop offeres better support for Internet Explorer when getting and setting attributes.

Comment: I want reset dropdownlist on every postback

Comment: As I said $("#target").val($("#target option:first").val()); this would be the best solution.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
                $("#productNameDDL").val($("#productNameDDL option:first").val());
            });
           
        }); I write this code inside this function but don't work what am i missing something

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to use "first" and target the elements attribute

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
    $("#productNameDDL option:first").attr('selected','selected');
  });
});
```